# how to have custom dialog as listview itemClickListener in android

Tags: android, onitemclicklistener, customdialog

i want to use a custom Dialog in my android project as clicking on listview's items

i customize my dialog in differt class as below:

```
 public class CustomDialogOption extends Dialog {
    public Activity activity;
    public Button dialog_delete, dialog_edit;
    public TextView dialog_msg;

    public CustomDialogOption (Activity a) {
        super(a);
        this.activity = a;
    }

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.dialog_counting);

        dialog_msg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dialogContet);
        dialog_delete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.delete);
        dialog_edit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.edit);




        dialog_msg.setText("..." + user_number.get(i) + " "
                + user_vow.get(i) + " " + user_why.get(i));
        dialog_delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        user_number.get(i) + " "
                                + " delete..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            }
        });
```

and i want to show this dialog on my listview clicking as below: MainActiviyclass

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
private ListView listView;


public final static ArrayList<String> user_number = new ArrayList<String>();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    //remain numbers -item click listener for Done-vow
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, final int i, long l) {


            CustomDialogOption cdo = new CustomDialogOption(MainActivity.this ,i);
            cdo.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
            cdo.show();
        }
    });
```

}

my problem is that how can i have relation ship between `OnItemClickListener` method (int i) and `CustomDialogOption` class. "i" parameter is not define. what can i do? thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Define an int i or whatever you name it in CustomDialogOption.

Add `int i` as param to constructor like this

```
 public CustomDialogOption (Activity a, Int i) {
            super(a);
            this.activity = a;
            this.i = i;    
        }
```

and call it like this

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, final int i, long l) {
            CustomDialogOption cdo = new CustomDialogOption(MainActivity.this, i);
            cdo.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
            cdo.show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: i do so, but my app has stopped

Comment: This is how you can link. For the crash part please share proper logs. Also I am seeing `user_number.get(i)` in your `CustomDialogOption` class but not seeing any declaration of `user_number`.

Comment: 04-18 07:12:58.265 24118-24152/vow_note.maxsoft.com.vownote E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb3fd8270

Comment: user_number is an ArrayList that i define in MainActivity where i want to use listviewSetOnItemClickListener

Comment: Your CustomDialogOption class is defined in the yout MainActivity class?

Comment: i define it in onItemClick method of MainActivity class

Comment: `public ArrayList<String> user_number = new ArrayList<String>(); `
It has no data defined ? it is empty how you can get value from it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109417/discussion-between-haris-aftab-and-mina-dahesh).